# Can't access many parts of Steam?

Tags: steam

For some reason, I am now unable to access much of the Steam site. When I click to go to the Store or my profile, it will just load for quite a while and then give me the "Error Code: -7" page. The only things I can access on Steam now seem to be my Library and other people's profiles page.

Comment: Has anything been changed recently? Are you going through a proxy, or have you been accessing steam in an unusual way before?

Comment: Can you access the same pages that give you the error through your web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the fault of my modem. It was broken somehow and I had to buy a new one.